# Establishing database Connection in php where mysql is in program files not in xampp

Tags: php, mysql

When I am installing XAMPP I have not installed MySQL where I have already using this database so I have not installed using xampp but in my PHP code when I am establishing connection I wrote

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

At $servername, everyone is keeping localhost and explaining PHPMyAdmin examples where MySQL is installed in xampp

In my case MySQL is at c:/programfiles/MySQL what I have to give at my $servername

Please help me, I am new to programming

Comment: localhost as i suppose your user is still local server

Answer (score 0):

*localhost* isn't the name of your MySQL server's install directory. It's a reference to your local machine aka `127.0.0.1`. Your server name is still *localhost*.

The only time you'll change this is if you host the database on a different machine.

Comment: Thank you very much you saves my time

Comment: @user2500694: If that answered your question, please accept the answer. :)